# Thunderbird stops authenticating via gmail SMTP until restarted

Tags: thunderbird, gmail, smtp

I have Mozilla Thuderbird 91.11.0 (64-bit) configured with a gmail account and a MS account via Owl.

My problem is that after an hour or two, outgoing mail via gmail and SMTP fails to authenticate requiring me to restart Thunderbird. I can still receive email from gmail and send/receive from my MS account.

Everything initially works but after a short period if I attempt to sent an email via gmail the sending dialog never completes. If I cancel the message I get a popup with:

*Login to server smtp.gmail.com with username xxxx@gmail.com failed.*

And a request to enter a new password. Re-entering the password does not help.

If I cancel out of this dialog I get:

*Sending of the message failed.
Unable to authenticate to Outgoing server (SMTP) smtp.gmail.com. Please check the password and verify the 'Authentication method' in 'Account Settings | Outgoing server (SMTP)'.*

If I close out of Thunderbird and then restart it and everything works fine for another hour or two and then the problem starts again.

Comment: You should set your GMail to OAuth2 in Thunderbird, not using the standard auth mechanisms.  That will give you better functionality overall.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Its already using OAuth2 however.